# Cannot find client id when creating a service account

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a service account to use Google API's for gmail. However, I cannot find the client ID to provide domain wide access, as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount .

There is a Service Account ID , but no client ID. Also, while creating a service account, it gives 2 default accounts - App engine and compute engine and there is no mention in documentation if I should be using that.

It also asks to give a service account name, unlike earlier where it used to generate the Service Account Name. Looks like documentation has not been updated to capture these changes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Service accounts don't have client ids they have "Service account ID".  Client id is Oauth2.  Note: are you sure service accounts work with gmail?

Comment: Service accounts do work with gmail and they also have client id. I have used it in the past but things seem to have changed now and there is no documentation for those changes.

Comment: I guess then it depends on how long its been since you used it.  Remember client login no longer works.  As far I can see server sided authentication documentation for Gmail is Oauth2 https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server.   Service accounts are pre authorized do you remember how you pre authorized the service account in the past?   It would be interesting to know if it did actually work.  Also I have been working with Google APIs for 4 years service accounts have NEVER had a client id. sorry

Comment: I have used it as late as 6-8 months back and yes they do have a client ID which is used for domain wide delegation.

Comment: Google luck then. Sorry I cant help. I still think you are confusing "service accounts" with "server sided authentication" using Oauth2 credentials.   If you do get it working with "service account" credentials please post your code I would be very interested in seeing how you pre-authorize a service account to gmail.

Comment: Have you enabled domain-wide delegation for the service account you want to use?  Once you've done that, there will be a "View Client ID" option for the service account in the [Service Accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts) in Cloud console.